# GOST 34.12-2015. C# Realization. L-operation mistake

Tags: c#, encryption

I am trying to make a realization of new GOST algorithm, but I got a problem with an L-operation. Here is my code and a screenshot of one round of it's encription\decription result:

```
static void Main()
    {
        string A = "You are welcome!";
        Console.WriteLine(A);
        byte[] _A = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(A);
        Console.WriteLine("\nEntered string as bytes :");
        for (int i = 0; i < _A.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(Convert.ToString(_A[i]) + " ");
        }
        byte[] _B = KuzR(_A);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nEncripted string as bytes :");
        for (int i = 0; i < _B.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(Convert.ToString(_B[i]) + " ");
        }
        byte[] _C = KuzRReverse(_B);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nDecripted string as bytes :");
        for (int i = 0; i < _C.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(Convert.ToString(_C[i]) + " ");
        }
        string B = Encoding.Default.GetString(_C);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n" + B);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static byte KuzMulInGF(byte a, byte b)
    {
        byte p = 0;
        byte counter;
        byte hi_bit_set;
        for (counter = 0; counter < 8 && a != 0 && b != 0; counter++)
        {
            if ((b & 1) != 0)
                p ^= a;
            hi_bit_set = (byte)(a & 0x80);
            a <<= 1;
            if (hi_bit_set != 0)
                a ^= 0xc3; /* x^8 + x^7 + x^6 + x + 1 */
            b >>= 1;
        }
        return p;
    }

    static byte[] LVec = new byte[]
    {1, 148, 32, 133, 16, 194, 192, 1,
251, 1, 192, 194, 16, 133, 32, 148};

    static byte[] KuzR(byte[] input)
    {
        byte a_15 = 0;
        byte[] state = new byte[16];
        for (int i = 15; i > 0; i--)
        {
            state[i - 1] = input[i];
            a_15 ^= KuzMulInGF(input[i], LVec[i]);
        }
        state[15] = a_15;
        return state;
    }

    static byte[] KuzL(byte[] input)
    {
        byte[] state = input;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            state = KuzR(state);
        }
        return state;
    }

    static byte[] KuzRReverse(byte[] input)
    {
        byte a_0;
        a_0 = input[15];
        byte[] state = new byte[16];
        for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
        {
            state[i] = input[i - 1];
            a_0 ^= KuzMulInGF(input[i], LVec[i]);
        }
        state[0] = a_0;
        return state;
    }

    static byte[] KuzLReverse(byte[] input)
    {
        byte[] state = input;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            state = KuzRReverse(state);
        }
        return state;
    }
```

[Screenshot of the one round of work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Hbb.png)

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I'd start by removing the string/byte[] conversions. Work with hard-coded byte arrays. If you can encrypt then decrypt byte arrays, you can do the same with text with the extra conversions. (I'd strongly recommend against using `Encoding.Default` though.)

Comment: Jon, i am using a text just to get a byte[] massive for encription. That code is from a different program, which makes only an L-conversion. It just doesn't decript an original byte[] massive correctly and i don't know where is a mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "massive" here, but as I say, I would encourage you to focus on *just* the encryption parts. Skip the conversion to and from strings.

Comment: Ok, i will try, and i meaned arrays, sorry for bad english.

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest showing the output as text within your question rather than showing screenshots. You may want to use `BitConverter.ToString(byte[])` as a much simpler way of showing a byte array than your current code.

Comment: Ok, i will bear this in mind, thanks